# Binding multiple DragSources for a signle draggable react-dnd entity

Tags: reactjs, drag-and-drop, react-dnd

I have a use-case, where I need two different parts of a component to serve as a `DragSource` for a single draggable card.

I tried implementing this naively, trying to pass `connectDragSource` as a ref to two different elements:

```js
const Card: FC = () => {
  const [, connectDragSource, connectDragPreview] = useDrag({ /* ... */ })

  return (
    <div className="wrapper">
      <div className="handle" ref={connectDragSource} />
      <div
        className="preview"
        ref={ref => {
          connectDragSource(ref)
          connectDragPreview(ref)
        }}
      />
    </div>
  )
}
```

but this way the latter ref overwrites the prior ("preview" is draggable, but "handle" is not).

Is there a legitimate way of achieving this, or do I have to call `useDrag` twice?

Comment: Unfortunately, I haven't found a solution and ended up using two `useDrag` calls :/